# Why do `cw` and `ce` do the same thing?

Tags: cursor-motions, vi-words

This has always bugged me about the `w` and `W` motion commands—they seem to work differently when used with the `c`hange command than they do when used alone, or with the `d`elete command.

---

For example, with the cursor on the "q" of this text:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

typing `dw` results in

```
The brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

and typing `de` results in

```
The  brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

(Notice the two spaces between "The" and "brown".)

---

The `y`ank command also treats `w` and `e` differently, as can be shown by comparing `yeP`:

```
The quickquick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

and `ywP`:

```
The quick quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

---

**However, typing either `ceslow<Esc>` or `cwslow<Esc>` results in the same thing**:

```
The slow brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Is this documented somewhere?  What is the logic behind it and how can I predict the results of a command that uses `w`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a special case. Check [the documentation for WORD](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#WORD), under "Special case":

> Special case: "cw" and "cW" are treated like "ce" and "cE" if the cursor is on a non-blank.  This is because "cw" is interpreted as
>   change-word, and a word does not include the following white space. 
>   {Vi: "cw" when on a blank followed by other blanks changes only the
>   first blank; this is probably a bug, because "dw" deletes all the
>   blanks}
>
> Another special case: When using the "w" motion in combination with an
>   operator and the last word moved over is at the end of a line, the end
>   of that word becomes the end of the operated text, not the first word
>   in the next line.
>
> The original Vi implementation of "e" is buggy.  For example, the "e"
>   command will stop on the first character of a line if the previous
>   line was empty. But when you use "2e" this does not happen.  In Vim
>   "ee" and "2e" are the same, which is more logical.  However, this
>   causes a small incompatibility between Vi and Vim.

Comment: Neovim 0.2.1 adds a 'cpoptions' flag "_" (underscore) which toggles this behavior. https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'cpoptions'

Answer (score 11):

The difference between the behavior of the motion in `cw` vs. `dw` can be explained simply: normally if you want to change a word you're going to leave the whitespace following it, while deleting a word suggests you want the whitespace to also be removed.

If you do want the whitespace to go away for some reason (I do it regularly enough but can't think of an example) then use the `aw` motion: `caw`.

Comment: Just want to add to [dash-tom-bang](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13860/41425) 's answer: `caw` is good when you want to change the whole word and its tailing space. For some cases if you want to change from the current point to the next word but keep letters before the cursor intact, you can use `vwc`.

Comment: @XuanWang the problem with `vwc` is that it will also replace the first character of the next word. At least under `:set sélection=inclusive`, which is the default behavior.

Comment: As an example for `caw`: if you want to replace `lone wolf` with `werewolf`, with the cursor before `lone`, you can type `cawwere`. Just typing `cwwere` would result in `were wolf`.