# Visual mode word behaves differently than in normal mode?

Tags: visual-mode, normal-mode, vi-words

Say I have the text:

```
This is a test!
```

If my cursor is on the first character, "T", and then I do `d4w`, then I am left with just `!`. However, if instead I do `v4wd` then I'm left with nothing (i.e. the entire string was selected and deleted).

Why is this the case? I saw there are some [special cases](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6197/29040) with words when searching for an answer, but it doesn't seem to exactly apply from my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim motions can be either inclusive ("include the rightmost character"), or exclusive ("exclude rightmost character"). `w` is made exclusive (so you delete exactly four words: "this" "is" "a" "test"). If you want to make it inclusive add `:h o_v` to the target command: `d4vw`.

Now, in Visual mode all motions are governed by a global option called `:h 'selection'`. By default, it's `:set selection=inclusive`, so `!` gets into the visual selection. Add `:set selection=exclusive` to your vimrc if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a special case, the examples are different. In the first one you say "delete 4 words", in the second you say "move 4 words to the right and then delete all that was selected", they mean different things. In the first case the first word to be deleted is `This` and the fourth word to be deleted is `test`, in the second case the first word the cursor is moved to is `is` and that the fourth word is `!`.

You can see it better by typing `4w` in normal mode with the cursor in `T`, you will see that the cursor is on top of `!`, just like in visual mode